# How to make a iframe in php

Tags: php, html, iframe

I have a question about iframes, but i realy don't know how to start with it. I think its the best to give the url inmediatly. http://www.nielsjansen.be/project/saved.php

When you click at the body of the article, the article opens in the same window, that's good, but i want to keep my menu etc. How is this possible?

Thank you

Comment: iframes are part of HTML, not PHP. Check http://www.iframehtml.com/

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your level of expertise in PHP and HTML, but I would not use IFRAMEs as they tend to be deprecated.

As @Aziz said, too, IFRAMEs are in the HTML and non in the PHP domain.

If you can edit your code and are able to program in PHP, a very basic technique would be to write down a function that outputs your menu ad use it in every page, including the article pages. That's the caveman solution, to get more complicated one should think about layout, content management and so on.

If you cannot program in PHP, things get a lot more difficult.

Comment: ok yes, but the links open in the same windows, so how can i add menu to the top of the page?

Answer (score 0):

You actually are asking an HTML question here. Since I don't have a sample of your code, I'll just take a shot at it:

```
<a href="mylink.html" target="myframe">
<iframe name="myframe" src="mypage.html"></iframe>
```

That should get you started. All you need to do is give a `name` attribute to your iframe, and a `target` to your link.

NOTE: I would strongly recommend *against* using iframes, as they have been deprecated as of HTML5, but have *always* (IMHO) been bad practice. There has only been one case where I used them in a project, which, if I had really set my mind to it, could have been avoided completely.

Hope that helps.